# Append timestamp to custom logging?

Tags: 20.04, cron, timestamp

I got a crontab running every night 2 in the morn'

`0 2 * * * sudo sh /net/vmits0356/disc1/misc/dupdate.sh >> /net/vmits0356/disc1/misc/dupdate.log`

I cannot seem to find how to append time to each line it writes into the log. The log works fine, but I'd like to have every line with a timestamp. Is that possible?

Comment: ... pipe it through `ts` ?

Comment: Do what now with the pipe?

Comment: See: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/ts.1.html

Comment: I don't get how I can do that with >> .-..

Comment: just a thought, watch the log file with

auditctl -w /path/to/that/file -p wa

Comment: more simply  put in a  'date >> logfile' then a ;     then your ' sh command '

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555327/multiple-sequential-commands-in-cron

Comment: pierrely, that's the best solution. Make an answer please, so I can solve it here.